# Top 3 frequency of words in a sentence

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

I've been asked to define a function to return the top used 3 words in a sentence. I've been able to compile a desired sentence into a dictionary so that something like

```
'test test bye bye hello hello world world world'
```

is in the form

```
{'world': 3, 'hello': 2, 'bye': 2, 'test': 2}
```

However, I only want the top 3 used words and as can be seen, there is a clash between 3 elements of the dictionary. Where there's a clash, the clashed words are best sorted alphabetically so that only 3 values are returned. In this case, I'd want:

```
['world','bye','hello']
```

to be returned after the sorting. How could I go by doing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `key` function of `sorted`, along with the way that tuples are inherently sorted, to do this:

```
>>> d = {'world': 3, 'hello': 2, 'bye': 2, 'test': 2}
>>> [x for x, y in sorted(d.items(), key=lambda (x, y): (-y, x))[:3]]
['world', 'bye', 'hello']
```

Comment: I think `[x for x, y in sorted(d.items(), key=lambda (x, y): (-y, x))[:3]]` would be slightly neater; you don't gain any benefit from `itertiems` here, as all items are needed for sorting, and having `x` refer to two different things in the same line is pretty awkward.

Comment: You're probably right. It's just habit for me to use `iteritems`!

Answer (score 1):

As a more pythonic way for such problem you can use `Counter` function  from `collections` module to get the proper dictionary then use `sorted` and a simple slicing the extract the desire pairs :

```
>>> s='test test bye bye hello hello world world world'
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> sorted(Counter(s.split()).items(),key=lambda (i,j):(-j,i))[:3]
[('world', 3), ('bye', 2), ('hello', 2)]
```

Comment: *"Elements with equal counts are ordered arbitrarily"* (see [the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter.most_common)), so this does **not** meet the OP's requirements

Comment: @jonrsharpe sorry i can understand what difference does it make?

Comment: Just **look at the examples** - the OP wants `'world'`, `'bye'` and `'hello'` (as they put it, *"the clashed words are best sorted alphabetically"*), whereas your version gives `'world'`, `'test'` and `'bye'`

Comment: @jonrsharpe aha, the order is *alphabetically* , i'll update it!

Comment: This is definitely much cleaner but sadly I'm not allowed to import anything. It must all be done raw.

Comment: This is just a simpler way to build the dictionary; the actual sorting is identical to [Ben's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29488134/3001761).

Comment: @Sundrah Include the "i m not allowed to import" in your question.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Yeah, the type of sort is very frequent in SO, and Ben gave my upvote too, anyway i thought that this is more elegant and i didn't remove my answer! as its obvious 10 repo does't make me discover the secret of universe ;)

Comment: But the text still reads *"you can use `Counter.most_common` method"*, which has never been true.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Yeah sure! i forgot it!